# Recompress 7z archives to tar.zst on the fly

Tags: pipe, tar, 7z, zstd

I have a bunch of [7z](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/7z) archives (containing directories and files) that I would like to recompress as [tar.zst](https://facebook.github.io/zstd/) (which offers much better decompression speeds if / when I need to unarchive them).

I could manually decompress them, then recompress with `tar -cvf --zstd foo.tar.zst foo/` but that means having the fully decompressed files on disk which isn't great from a disk utilization PoV.

Is it possible to "stream" the files (using `|` somehow) from 7z to tar, to recompress those files without having the decompressed files on disk? If so would a similar solution apply to `rar` / `zip` / other archive types?

Comment: Search the manpages for writing to "standard output" or stdout and reading from stdin. Then you can pipe the stdout from one program to the stdin of the next. 7z and zip seem to support this, but tar doesn't seem to be as straightforward. If you think your disk is slow and you are not working with huge archives then you could also look into mounting a piece of RAM and using that as your temp directory. If you want to do this for multiple archives you can save some time with (for) loops and replacing file name extensions (using a "globbing pattern") in bash or whatever shell you prefer.

Comment: @Higemaru you can’t pipe data from an archive containing multiple files and construct a new archive containing those files, at least not without going to a huge amount of effort (you’d have to list all the files from the original, along with any other metadata you want to preserve, then extract them one by one, feeding them to `tar` along with the metadata extracted previously).

Comment: @Stephen: Hmmm... That makes sense... I guess it's not really possible if there are multiple files. Out of curiosity, if I wanted to convert `tar.gz` to `tar.zst`, would it be possible since technically the archive is just a single tar file?

Comment: With tarballs it’s much simpler: `gunzip -c foo.tar.gz | zstd -o foo.tar.zstd`.

Comment: @StephenKitt you're right, seems we can't do that. :) I wondered how multiple files would work. But then, what *does* 7z do when asked to output to stdout? Does it refuse if there are multiple files, or does it have some (custom) format for outputting multiple files + metadata as a binary blob? I never tried.

Comment: @Higemaru it outputs the file contents to standard output, with nothing else; it does so even if the archive contains multiple files. There might be an option to get it to output metadata too, or at least file names, as `unzip -c` does; but that can’t be used to identify files since a given file could contain the header as well.

Answer (score 1):

If disk writes are your concern and your RAM is large enough to host the files and do the (de)compressing operations, you may use a temporary `ramfs`. I suggest this over `tempfs` as `ramfs` grows dynamically with the content and does not use swap - so no disk writes and no thinking about the size beforehand. Also speed with RAM-only operations is increased.

```
mkdir -p /mnt/ram
mount -t ramfs ramfs /mnt/ram
```

Then extract to there and compress from there. Be aware that the date will be lost in case of a power-failure or alike, so make sure to have the `tar.zst` ready before deleing the `.7z`-file.

Comment: man 7z says there is an option  -so    Write data to StdOut

Comment: @Higemaru ah yes, missed that one.

Comment: Interesting idea! I guess that would work for smaller files but the reason I wanted to do without actually storing the raw files was because they are pretty big (20GB+) so RAM might not be large enough. Thanks though!